# Returning MySQL data to cakephp view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am pretty new to cakephp and I am banging my head against the wall trying to write a pretty basic statement.

In my view file, I want to say if the is_open column in the events table is true, echo something. If it is not true, echo something else.

```
<?php
  if ($response['data']['Event']['is_open'] == true) {
     echo "Yes";
  } else {

     echo "No";
  }
 ?>
```

I am having trouble working backwards within the controller to get the data in the first place.

In my controller I have something this:

```
    public function some_function() {
    $events = $this->Event->find('all');
}
```

In my view file, I get this error:

Notice (8): Undefined index: Event [View/Applications/agreement.ctp, line 21]

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

I have been going through the blog tutorial and it's clear in some places to me and not clear in others. Where I am still having trouble is displaying anything in the view.

After further reading I want to do something like this in the controller:

```
$myVariable = $this->Event->find('first', 
   array( 'fields' => 'Event.is_open ', 
   'conditions' => array('Event.id =' => '400') ));
```

What I am hoping to say is grab the is_open value from the events table where the events.id = 400 (later on this value will be dynamic) Does this look even remotely correct? – mmalv just now edit

Comment: provide a debug of $events and you will probably see for yourself what is wrong

Comment: Please provide a working/complete example. you refer to `$response`, `$events`, `$myVariable` in the question - there's no way to tie them together.

Answer (score 1):

How did you come up with `$response['data']`?

In your `EventsController` you correctly set the return of `$this->Event->find('all')` to `$events`. In order for this variable to be available to your view you need to call `Controller::set` on it like this:

```
$this->set('events', $events);
```

Or even simpler, in one step, you can just do:

```
$this->set('events', $this->Event->find('all'));
```

Then in your Event view (perhaps someplace like `View/Events/index.ctp`) access the variable by the name `$events`. It should be in the format

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
    'Event' => Array(
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'An open name!',
      'is_open' => true
    )
  ),
  [1] => Array(
    'Event' => Array(
      'id' => 1,
      'name' => 'Another event but closed',
      'is_open' => false
    )
  )
)
```

So now all you need in your view is to run a loop like:

```
foreach ($events as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['Event']['is_open']) {
    echo "Yes";
  } else {
    echo "No";
  }
}
```

All this is thoroughly explained in the cookbook, just go through the blog tutorial.

Comment: I have been going through the blog tutorial and it's clear in some places to me and not clear in others. Where I am still having trouble is displaying anything in the view.

After further reading I want to do something like this in the controller:

$myVariable = $this->Event->find('first', array(
       'fields' => 'Event.is_open ',
       'conditions' => array('Event.id =' => '400')
    ));

What I am hoping to say is grab the is_open value from the events table where the events.id = 400 (later on this value will be dynamic)

Does this look even remotely correct?

Comment: Of course it is possible - and it is easy!
You just seem to need some more time to grasp everything, take it easy and try to understand the examples instead of just copying them over and banging your head over the results.

If you know your ID already (and it is valid) then set it to the model like:
`$this->Event->id = 400;`
Then your model will contain the data of that record and you just need something like:
`$isOpen = $this->Event->field('is_open');`
Don't forget to `Controller::set()` it to have it available in your view.

Comment: Also if you haven't already, enable DebugKit and use `debug();` to have a look at what is returned or contained in your variables. In the **view** if you `debug($this->_viewVars());` you can take a look at what is passed from the controller to the view.